# How to overide a class public static function?

Tags: php, class, function, static, public

How do you override a class public static function without editing that file? Let's say that I have a class file name Display and inside that class has a public static function called body open.

```
class Display {
    public static function body_open() {
        echo "\n" . '</head><!-- End <head> -->' . "\n\n";
        echo '<body class="' . self::body_class() . '">' . "\n\n";
        do_action('headway_body_open');
        echo "\n" . '<div id="zurbwrap">' . "\n";
        do_action('headway_whitewrap_open');
        do_action('headway_page_start');
    }

    public static function body_close() {
        echo "\n\n";
        do_action('headway_whitewrap_close');
        echo '</div><!-- #zurbwrap -->' . "\n";
        do_action('headway_body_close');
        echo "\n" . '</body>';
    }
}
```

Let's say I want to change the div wrapper of body_open public static function. How do I do it without touching the core class file? is there a way to override it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP 5.3+, you can use late static binding: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

Anything before 5.3 means you will probably have to rethink your current implementation/architecture for that particular class.

Answer (score 1):

Use [late static bindings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php), if you're using PHP 5.3+.